# Show Alertdialog and use vibrator

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-vibration

I'm having a class that implements RecognitionListener like this:

```
public class listener implements RecognitionListener
```

I wanted to show a alertdialog and use the vibrator but this isn't possible because I need to provide a context what I don't have.

My alertdialog code was like this:

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("dd")
        .setMessage("aa")
        .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

            }
         })
         .show();
```

But the AlertDialog.Builder(this) wants a context, the same problem with my vibrator code:

```
v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

The getSystemService method isn't available.

My code that starts the class:

```
sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5); 
sr.startListening(intent);
```

Whats the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor that takes a context object would work well here.

Declare a context variable

```
private Context mContext;
```

Then declare a constructor that takes a context

```
public listener(Context context){
    super();
    mContext = context
}
```

When you need a context use mContext instead of `this`.

When you create the listener pass the current context

```
sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener(this));
```

Also as an aside in Java class names should always start with a capital so your class should be Listener not listener

Comment: Thanks. The super() is that in reference to the implements RecognitionListener class? That I call that constructor?

Comment: The super() is not necessary as the compiler will put it in for you but it does specify the RecognitionListener constructor which is called, I like to explicitly state it as a reminder that it is being invoked